# css background images not always displayed

Tags: css, firefox, background, browser-cache

I am loading background images with css:

```
background:#000000 url(site/logo.jpg) no-repeat
```

This works fine. However, using Firefox, when reloading the site with forced cache refresh the images sometimes do not show up. In these cases I need to take some clicking action (e.g. switching tabs, marking text, right-clicking and viewing site info or source) to make them appear. I assume that they are loaded but simply not displayed.

This does not happen when Firefox is loading the site without forced cache refresh even if the cache is empty. It does not occur using IE or Chrome. In fact, it seems this did not happen before the recent Firefox 19 release but I am not sure about that.

I cannot find any obvious reason. Are there other things that could have an influence on this?

Comment: Have you checked that it is indeed loaded but not displayed with a tool like Firebug?
Otherwise you should put the url in quotes. It's probably not causing the problem but that the right way to do it

Comment: What method are you using to force the cache refresh?

Comment: Simply refreshing with CTRL F5.

Comment: You should install Firebug, you won't be able to debug anything (in Firefox) without it. And to back charly's comment, put a semicolon at the end of the expression.

Comment: Installed it. Adding quotes and semicolon did not change anything. Simply activating Firebug results in the images showing up, without having changed anything. Anyway, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Firefox update 19.0.2 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try use separately:

`background:url('site/logo.jpg') no-repeat;`
`background-color: #000;`

I have tried this code in my browser (Firefox 19.0) and works fine even after refresh with F5 !
If this doesn't work for you, send a link of your page. Maybe it's because the element on wich you apply this style ... or who knows, there can be many posibilities.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue.
Our images has been placed in table as a background of `<th>` and `<td>`.

Look at end of this 
[post](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-83176.html)
and solution roposed by **yasirmturk**

1. add `<div style=‘clear:both’></div>` before the end of wrapper DIV
2. add `overflow:hidden;` to wrapper DIV
3. add `display:inline-block;` to wrapper DIV

Another way we have solved it was switch to

```
border-collapse: separate;
```